# Cross-platform exec system call from Java

Tags: java, process, cross-platform

Java already has built-in functionality to execute commands with or without using the system command interpreter. The functionality in [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and  [`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) provides this. However, neither of these classes allow you to replace the process with the one you're executing; they just spawn a child process and continue.

What the `exec()` function (and variants like `execl` and `execv`) does is it (essentially) replaces the current process with the one specified by the exec call. It's available both on [POSIX systems](https://web.archive.org/web/20170801030405/) and on [Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20171107164124/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/exec-wexec-functions).

Is there any way to replicate its functionality in Java? In theory I could write native bindings for Windows, macOS, Linux, BSD, Solaris, etc. but that sounds like an extremely hacky solution for something that should in theory be possible to do in a cross-platform using pure Java.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Are you trying to run a different command for each OS?  "replaces the current process with the one specified by the exec call" makes it sound like you want to start a process and then let java exit

Comment: It's almost like that. The difference between replacing the process and starting a process and exiting the JVM is that replacing the process will appear to everyone else as if it never exited (for example, the PID will be the same).